# Erro de definição do método ExecuteSQL

Tags: java

Ao criar o método execute gera erro neste ponto  rs = stm.executeQuery(sql) o que posso fazer

```
public void excutaSQL(String sql){
        try {
            stm=(Statement) conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);// o erro está neste linha 
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

     }
```

> error: cannot find symbol
>               rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
>     symbol:   method executeQuery(String)
>     location: variable stm of type Statement
>   1 error

```
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

Comment: Onde esta o valor da tua variavel `SQL`

Comment: Qual é o error?

Comment: Provavelmente você está importando a biblioteca `Statement` da `java.beans` ao invés da `java.sql`. Coloca o `import` pra conferirmos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está importando a classe `Statement` errada. Altere o `import` da classe `Statement` para o seguinte:

```
import java.sql.Statement;
```

Ou apenas remova a linha abaixo, afinal você já está fazendo o `import` para todas as classes (com `import java.sql.*`):

```
import java.beans.Statement;
```

Documentação da classe [java.sql.Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)